# HTML & CSS - Centering text in header inbetween logo and button

Tags: html, css, header, navigation

How would i be able to align my navigation links to the header?
This is what i currently have: [image: Link between logo and button]
But, I'd really like to have the links vertically aligned within the header, like this: [image: Wanted result.]
How would i do this? 
Below is my CSS & HTML.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#top_header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #26ABF5;
  height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo_top {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 53px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#main_nav {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 170px;
}

#main_nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 6em;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 101px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #26abf5;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="top_header">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo_top" draggable="false" src="images/logo1.png"></a>
          <nav id="main_nav">
            <a href="#">FORSIDE</a>
            <a href="#">HVAD TILBYDER VI?</a>
            <a href="#">PRISER</a>
            <a href="#">OM OS</a>
          </nav>
            <a class="button" href="#">LOG IND</a>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use line-height for `vertical-align`. Im add the line in `#main_nav`.

**Edit:** add `float: left;` for your logo image.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#top_header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #26ABF5;
  height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo_top {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 53px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#main_nav {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 170px;
}

#main_nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 6em;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 101px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #26abf5;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="top_header">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo_top" draggable="false" src="images/logo1.png"></a>
          <nav id="main_nav">
            <a href="#">FORSIDE</a>
            <a href="#">HVAD TILBYDER VI?</a>
            <a href="#">PRISER</a>
            <a href="#">OM OS</a>
          </nav>
            <a class="button" href="#">LOG IND</a>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This didnt do anything? I can see, that it centers it in your example, but when i test it with the image of the logo added, nothing happens.

Comment: Also, here is a image of the logo, if you want to test it with that:

Comment: im edit my answer. just need to add float: left; for your logo image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! This worked like a charm. :)